# How can I return a class instance with a generic type as an interface with a generic type?

Tags: c#, generics

When I have a simple Class and Interface, I can do this:

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public IFoo Instance()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do the same thing when both are generics?

```
public class Base<T, TI>
{
    public TI Instance()
    {
        return this; // Nope
        return (T) this; // Nope
    }
}

public class Foo : Base<Foo, IFoo>
{

}
```

However I try to do this, I'm getting a "cannot implicitly convert type" error.

Comment: `return this; // Nope return (T) this; // Nope` of course it wouldn't work because `this` is `Base<T, TI>`, not `TI`. Just try to `public Base<T, TI>Instance()`

Comment: Do you mean if `IFoo<T>`? Problem is that your `Base` class doesn't implement interfaces open generic type...

Comment: No, that would not make sense. Also I do not see why you would want to, the first piece of code without the generics already expresses what you want to accomplish.

Comment: In the second snippet `this` is some closed variant of `Base<T, TI>` not `TI`

Comment: @Igor because I have 20 different classes that do what Foo does...

Comment: !stupidity possibility alert!  Can't all IFoo<T> derive from IFoo a la IEnumerable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# does not support this.

The best you can do is

```
public class Base<T, TI> where T : Base<T, TI>, TI
{
    public TI Instance()
    {
        return (TI) (object) this; // Yep
    }
}
```

Comment: @Johnny: He's trying to use CRTP; as long as the derived classes do that correctly, this is fine.

Comment: Agree, just worth mentioning.